# highlighting duplicate rows in excel by VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, duplicate

I have a matrix which includes different/same values in first column, and different values in first row.

I would like to compare all rows and highlight duplicate rows. For each row, it should check the combination of “+”, “-“ and “/” values and it should highlight the duplicate row pairs(triples etc…) in different colors.(different color for each duplicate pair)

It should also assume that three rows like below are duplicates.  It will accept “/” values as “+” & “-“ and it will highlight these rows also as duplicates.

Here is an example of the result of macro that I would like to have (rows in same color are duplicates) ;
[image]

**EDIT :** x4 & x7 are also duplicates with x1 & x2.And there are other duplicates which I did not colorized. I just colorized some of the duplicates in order to explain my problem.

Comment: What? "It will accept “/” values as “+” & “-” ..." -- I don't see anything _other_ than “/”, “+”, and “-”, so why aren't *all* the rows considered the same? And "row3 is a duplicate of row3"? What does your little text block mean? Does the red text signify anything?

Comment: Edited the text box...I made red texts in order to underline that for those cells, the "/" value behaves like "+" or "–"

Comment: I don't understand your system.  For example `x3 x9` appear to be the same, as do `x4 x7 x8 x10`  yet there does not appear to be marking setting them off.

Comment: yes you're right, I just gave some examples. I did not mention all table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restate your matching rules as follows (hopefully I am correct):

- `+` matches anything in the class `[+/]`
- `-` matches anything in the class `[-/]`
- `/` matches anything in the class `[-+/]`

Given that, it is a matter of creating a pattern from the string concatenation that will acta as a matching pattern.  This can be done using regular expressions, but VBA has a Like method which will work just as well, perhaps  faster.

We set things up by first Inserting a Class module and rename it cRowString

**Class Module**

```
Option Explicit
Private pRow As Long
Private pColA As String
Private pConcatString As String
Private pPattern As String

Public Property Get Row() As Long
    Row = pRow
End Property
Public Property Let Row(Value As Long)
    pRow = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ColA() As String
    ColA = pColA
End Property
Public Property Let ColA(Value As String)
    pColA = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ConcatString() As String
    ConcatString = pConcatString
End Property
Public Property Let ConcatString(Value As String)
    pConcatString = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Pattern() As String
    Pattern = pPattern
End Property
Public Property Let Pattern(Value As String)
    pPattern = Value
End Property
```

Next enter this **Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
Sub HilightDuplicateRows()
    Dim vData As Variant, lColors() As Long, V As Variant
    Dim colDups As Collection
    Dim R As Range
    Dim cR As cRowString, colRows As Collection
    Dim arrColors
    Dim S1 As String, S2 As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K1 As Long, K2 As Long, L As Long

arrColors = VBA.Array(vbRed, vbCyan, vbYellow, vbGreen)

'get original range and load data into array
Set R = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
I = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set R = R.Resize(columnsize:=I)

vData = R

'Iterate through and create patterns, collect them
Set colRows = New Collection
For I = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
    S1 = ""
    S2 = ""
    For J = 2 To UBound(vData, 2)
        S1 = S1 & vData(I, J)
        Select Case vData(I, J)
            Case "+"
                S2 = S2 & "[+/]"
            Case "-"
                S2 = S2 & "[-/]"
            Case "/"
                S2 = S2 & "[-+/]"
        End Select
    Next J
    Set cR = New cRowString
    With cR
        .Row = I
        .ColA = vData(I, 1)
        .ConcatString = S1
        .Pattern = S2
    End With
    colRows.Add cR
Next I

'Check for duplicate pairs
Set colDups = New Collection
For I = 1 To colRows.Count - 1
    For J = I + 1 To colRows.Count
        If colRows(I).ConcatString Like colRows(J).Pattern Then
            colDups.Add CStr(colRows(I).Row & "," & colRows(J).Row)
        End If
    Next J
Next I

'Color the rows
ReDim lColors(1 To UBound(vData, 1))
J = 0
For I = 1 To colDups.Count
    V = Split(colDups(I), ",")
    If IsArray(V) Then
        Select Case lColors(V(0))
            Case 0
                J = J + 1
                K1 = J Mod (UBound(arrColors) + 1)
                lColors(V(0)) = arrColors(K1)
                lColors(V(1)) = arrColors(K1)
            Case Else
                lColors(V(1)) = lColors(V(0))
        End Select
    Else
        lColors(V) = xlAutomatic
    End If
Next I

R.Interior.Color = xlAutomatic
For I = 1 To R.Rows.Count
If lColors(I) = 0 Then
    R.Rows(I).Interior.Color = xlAutomatic
Else
    R.Rows(I).Interior.Color = lColors(I)
End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Select the active sheet and run the macro

Comment: 1st of all, thank you for the code.

First- I've inserted a class module and pasted the first part of the code inside.

Then- I've inserted a (regular) module and pasted 2nd part of the code.

Finally, I ran the macro by selecting the active sheet with the data to be checked. I gives me following warning (http://imageshack.com/a/img913/3478/U6F1pV.jpg) and opens debugger. Do I make sth. wrong?

Here is screenshot of the the code debugging screen :http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6750/58Eka6.jpg

Here is the sample data that I run the macro : http://imageshack.com/a/img631/4632/IPStdS.jpg

Comment: You did not rename the class module as instructed.  You seem to have duplicated the class module code in the regular module.

Comment: Works like a charm after renaming the class module.Big thanks for the code...

Comment: @NT. You're welcome.  And you can easily modify it to add more colors, if necessary.  You'd need to add colors to arrColors, and also change the line `K1 = J Mod 4` to something like `K1 = J Mod (Ubound(arrColors) + 1)`

Comment: Which part do I need to edit for new colors? @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: @NT. Amazing, I was typing an answer as you were writing your question.  I just made the change in the `K1 =` line in my answer, so you only have to add colors to arrColors

Comment: even after updating the code for arrColors part of the code, I don't have enough colors to highlight different matching pairs. Any other way for doing this color numbers increase?  @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: @NT.  How many do you need?  You should read about the Color property.  The VBA constants I used are only a shorthand for a very few of the more than 16,000,000 possible RGB values (colors). Although many of them will be impractical due to overlap.  Or you could use a different property to set the color, using a similar technique of cycling through an array of values (or even an array of arrays).  You might need to make arrColors an array of arrays, as with some of the colors you might want to change the font color also.  But you've got plenty of options.

Comment: In fact 10 different colors are enough for me but when I run the macro it repeats the colors after 4. @ Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: @NT. Did you change the `K1 = ` line as I mentioned in my comments and in the edited code in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I use your updated code. @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: @NT. Could you post a workbook with sample data, and the code you are using, on some site like OneDrive, or DropBox, and then post a link here.  I'll take a look and try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21286/discussion-between-nt-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Comment: Here is the example pattern to be checked for duplications. I created the macro inside this file as well. https://yadi.sk/i/okjRajjeeoKHH @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: @NT. The reason you only see four colors is because you only have four colors listed in arrColors. See my comment above

Comment: hmm I understood finally :), I will check google for a complete list of colors to add in code's "arrColors = VBA.Array(vbRed, vbCyan, vbYellow, vbGreen)" field.

Comment: @NT. You can add any RGB value; you are not limited to only the colors for which there are color constants.

Comment: Ok got it now :) I can use lots of rgbXxxx colors now.Big thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps concatenate the content (col-F), count the matches (col-G), then apply a conditional format based on the count quantity.

This approach means two row sets having the same count qty will have the same color.

[image: XL count concatenate]

[image: XL conditional formatting]

Comment: this method highlights only the rows which are exactly same. It does not take into account "/" should be assumed as "+" or "-" during duplicate detecting. So it's does not solve my problem.Moreover, as it's done by conditional formatting not by VBA macro, it's not applicable for me.

Comment: +1 as this is a creative way of doing what *appeared* to be what he was looking for